# if condition not working properly always pick else part

Tags: android, if-statement

```
This condition is for gcm notification get activity



public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    // Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
    public static final int notifyID = 9001;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    int count, i;

    public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                        + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                    .equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n"
                        + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
            }
        }
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {

        Log.d("Notification-msssg", msg);
        Log.d("Notification-msssg", msg);

        if (msg.equals("Property")) {

            Log.d("Notification-msssg", msg + "chat");
            Log.d("Notification-msssgchat", msg);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MessageListActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("CPO")
                    .setContentText("You've received new message.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconnotifi);
            // Set pending intent
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);

            // Set the content for Notification
            mNotifyBuilder
                    .setContentText("New message on your property, Check it");
            // Set autocancel
            mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Post a notification

            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());

            // mNotifyBuilder.build().sound = Uri
            // .parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"
            // + getPackageName() + "/raw/kalimba");

            // Uri uri =
            // RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            //
            // builder.setSound(uri);

        } else {

            Log.d("Notification-msssg", msg + "property");
            Log.d("Notification-msssgproperty", msg);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResidencialActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("CPO")
                    .setContentText("You've new Property to check")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.iconnotifi);
            // Set pending intent
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
            int defaults = 0;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
            defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

            mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);

            // Set the content for Notification
            mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New Property Added, Check it");
            // Set autocancel
            mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            // Post a notification

            mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());

        }

    }
}
```

the if condition not working properly, i don't know whats the issue, it always going in else part of condition, the check value is right but not pic if part.. but when i change it into msg.equals(msg), than it pic the if part ..

this check is for changing the start activity on notification get, i have to activity for notification getting activities..

Any solution for this issue...

Comment: i change the values to 1 or 2 also but it still not work

Comment: What is your msg string?

Comment: @FebiMathew msg string is message coming from notification and it is "Property"  or other one is "Message"...

Comment: Check whether "Property" string contains any space.

Comment: @FebiMathew sir i check it there is no space in msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling method as sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());. So msg string contains "Send error: ......". Then how it becomes equals to "Property"???

Answer (score 0):

where do you expect that msg should equal to "Property"?

You are sending following 3 messages:

```
 sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
 sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: + extras.toString());
 sendNotification("Message Received from Google GCM Server:\n\n"
                        + extras.get(ApplicationConstants.MSG_KEY));
```

There is no single line where you send the value "Property" like this:

```
sendNotification("Property");
```